# Каким образом лучше спроектировать приложение?

Tags: архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование

Приложение представляет из себя парсер, который с разных источников собирает однотипные данные.
То есть основная сущность приложения будет всегда иметь одни и те же методы и свойства. Различаться будет только источник откуда эти данные нужно спарсить.
Само приложение должно быть выполнено в виде API.
С клиентской части будут приходить запросы на получения списка из какого-то конкретного источника, возможно поиск в конкретном источнике.
Первое проблемное место которое я вижу заключается в том, что данные которые нужно парсить достаточно нестабильны. Т.е. если завтра в одном из источников поменяется верстка все сломается и нужно будет править код. Соответственно это преложение должно легко поддерживаться.
На данный момент у меня есть две идеи:

1. Реализовать абстрактный класс в котором описать сущность + абстрактные методы для поиска данных. Наследовать от этого класса все остальные и описывать методы поиска для каждого отдельного источника
2. Реализовать отдельно класс который будет описывать сущность с методами которые относятся к бизнес-логике, и отдельно реализовать классы-репозитории для каждого источника. Типа как это реализовано в симфони.

Какой подход лучше? Может быть есть еще какие то концепции о которых я не знаю?

Comment: _поменяется верстка_ - исходя из этого, можно предположить, что вы собираетесь парсить веб-сайт. Однако, практически любую информацию можно получить из какого-нибудь API. Так вот, чтобы не создавать самому себе проблемы, найдите такой API и обращайтесь к нему. Да, возможно, не удастся найти бесплатный. Однако, те несколько у.е., которые будет стоить доступ к API будут меньше, чем оплата труда разработчика, вынужденного регулярно переписывать код.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да всё верно - парсить несколько веб сайтов. Не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду "найти такой API". На интересующих меня web-сайтах не реализовано API впринципе. Да и к тому же проект учебный.

Comment: Если проект учебный, то нет смысла заморачиваться с его поддержкой в случае изменения формата данных. | По поводу API. Например, вы парсите сайт погоды или курсов валют. Если у этих сайтов нет API, то можно поискать другие сервисы с API, предоставляющие такие данные (погоду или курсы валют и т. п.).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну с такой логикой можно вообще не заморачиваться. Если проект учебный, это не значит что нужно писать говнокод, и не задумываться о том как лучше его спроектировать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю сначала нужно реализовать вторую идею.
А когда накопится достаточно данных о разных источниках - можно ("кристаллизировать") реализовать первый универсальный вариант.

Либо собрать достаточно информации о каждом источнике и методе обработки данных, и реализовать первый вариант. Но это будет не просто в самом начале.